# Get all the values from the table and Count all the words with specific Word

Tags: php, mysql, function

Here is my Code

```
<?php

        for ($x = 0; $x <= $n; $x++)
        {
            //Counting of rows
            $countrow = get_rows($getvids);
 
            
            if($offline == "Offline")
             {


              $apsys = "APSYS";
              $offlined = "";

              if ($getvids == $apsys ||  $getvids == $offlined )
              {

              echo "<tr>
              <th>$x</th>
                <th>$accntid[$x]</th>
                <th>$fname[$x]</th>
                <th>$lname[$x]</th>
                <th>$vid[$x]</th>
                <th>$vplatenum[$x]</th>
                <th>$imei[$x]</th>
               <th>$datas[1]</th>
                <th>$datas[0]</th>
                <th>$offline</th>";
                echo "<th>$getvids</th>";
                echo "<th><button type = 'button' class = 'btn btn-success viewbtn'> View Troubleshoot Report History</button></th>";
                echo "</tr> "; 
                
                echo "total number of Rows:";
                echo str_word_count($countrow);

             }

             else
             {
              }
             }
            else
             {
                
             }  

                   
        }


         ?>
```

and here is my Function

```
<?php
function get_rows($getrowscount)
{
  require ('db_connection.php');

 $getrowscounts = $getrowscount;
 //echo $getrowscounts;

 return $getrowscounts;

}
//get_rows(); // call the function
?>
```

the table shows Two Rows with the value of = "APSYS"
I want to count the rows and show the output like this:
Total number of Rows: 2

but the output I can only get is like This:
Total number of Rows:1
Total number of Rows:1
Total number of Rows:0

can someone help me, I am a little bit confused about what will I use to count the rows?
Thanks.

Comment: Why don' you sum up  $countrow?

Comment: i don't have any  idea how to sum up the $countrow

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Does this satifsfy your requirement?

```
<?php
        $countrow = 0;
        for ($x = 0; $x <= $n; $x++)
        {
            //Counting of rows
            $countrow = $countrow + get_rows($getvids);
            if($offline == "Offline")
             {
                 //omitted
             }
             else
             {
              }
             }
        }
        echo "total number of Rows:";
        echo str_word_count($countrow);

?>
```

Comment: The Output is:
 total number of Device:0 total number of Device:0 total number of Device:0

Comment: What is "Device"? You didn' t mention that.

Comment: Oh Sorry my bad , the output was 

total number of Rows:0 total number of Rows:0 total number of Rows:0

Comment: Anyway, get_rows function seems to do nothing to me.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are trying to count them after fetching from the database, try to write a SQL query instead of your current approach.**